# How do I declare an array of undefined or no initial size?

Tags: c

I know it could be done using `malloc`, but I do not know how to use it yet.

For example, I wanted the user to input several numbers using an infinite loop with a sentinel to put a stop into it (i.e. -1), but since I do not know yet how many he/she will input, I have to declare an array with no initial size, but I'm also aware that it won't work like this int arr[]; at compile time since it has to have a definite number of elements.

Declaring it with an exaggerated size like *int arr[1000];* would work but it feels dumb (and waste memory since it would allocate that 1000 integer bytes into the memory) and I would like to know a more *elegant* way to do this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This can be done by using a pointer, and allocating memory on the heap using `malloc`.
Note that there is no way to later ask how big that memory block is. You have to keep track of the array size yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  /* declare a pointer to an integer */
  int *data; 
  /* we also have to keep track of how big our array is - I use 50 as an example*/
  const int datacount = 50;
  data = malloc(sizeof(int) * datacount); /* allocate memory for 50 int's */
  if (!data) { /* If data == 0 after the call to malloc, allocation failed for some reason */
    perror("Error allocating memory");
    abort();
  }
  /* at this point, we know that data points to a valid block of memory.
     Remember, however, that this memory is not initialized in any way -- it contains garbage.
     Let's start by clearing it. */
  memset(data, 0, sizeof(int)*datacount);
  /* now our array contains all zeroes. */
  data[0] = 1;
  data[2] = 15;
  data[49] = 66; /* the last element in our array, since we start counting from 0 */
  /* Loop through the array, printing out the values (mostly zeroes, but even so) */
  for(int i = 0; i < datacount; ++i) {
    printf("Element %d: %d\n", i, data[i]);
  }
}
```

That's it. What follows is a more involved explanation of why this works :)

I don't know how well you know C pointers, but array access in C (like `array[2]`) is actually a shorthand for accessing memory via a pointer. To access the memory pointed to by `data`, you write `*data`. This is known as dereferencing the pointer. Since `data` is of type `int *`, then `*data` is of type `int`. Now to an important piece of information: `(data + 2)` means "add the byte size of 2 ints to the adress pointed to by `data`".

An array in C is just a sequence of values in adjacent memory. `array[1]` is just next to `array[0]`. So when we allocate a big block of memory and want to use it as an array, we need an easy way of getting the direct adress to every element inside. Luckily, C lets us use the array notation on pointers as well. `data[0]` means the same thing as `*(data+0)`, namely "access the memory pointed to by `data`". `data[2]` means `*(data+2)`, and accesses the third `int` in the memory block.

Comment: Thanks. This is the comprehensive explanation I need, thank you for the extra effort sir, I can now code to try a few things based on your explanation. Last question though, how would I increase the array size, assuming I would like to extend it past 50 elements?

Comment: To increase the array size, you have to use `realloc`. This _might_ copy and move the entire memory block, so it's not cheap. http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc

Answer (score 19):

The way it's often done is as follows:

- allocate an array of some initial (fairly small) size;
- read into this array, keeping track of how many elements you've read;
- once the array is full, reallocate it, doubling the size and preserving (i.e. copying) the contents;
- repeat until done.

I find that this pattern comes up pretty frequently.

What's interesting about this method is that it allows one to insert `N` elements into an empty array one-by-one in amortized `O(N)` time without knowing `N` in advance.

Comment: Nice trick. This seems like a simple, and therefore, sensible answer.

Answer (score 6):

Modern C, aka C99, has [variable length arrays](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Variable-length_array), VLA. Unfortunately, not all compilers support this but if yours does this would be an alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't let you resize as you exceed the initial guess.

Comment: Thanks, I just found out about this and it's helpful. I'll still try to find out how to do this in C89 just for portability's sake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks GOD not all compilers support this!

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement dynamic data structure such as a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Comment: Agh. I can't count the number of C "veterans" I've run into who don't seem to realize that any other kind of dynamic storage scheme is even possible, let alone might be optimal. It seems like people never do move on from this. I would much rather recommend that they start out implementing something more like a vector, as aix suggests - the damage is much less in that case if they don't move on.

Comment: of course more efficient data structures are out there, in fact, the first thing occurred to me was using STL Vector before noticing that he was actually asking about C, linked list is more like a concept than a real data structure to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample program that reads `stdin` into a memory buffer that grows as needed.  It's simple enough that it should give some insight in how you might handle this kind of thing.  One thing that's would probably be done differently in a real program is how must the array grows in each allocation - I kept it small here to help keep things simpler if you wanted to step through in a debugger.  A real program would probably use a much larger allocation increment (often, the allocation size is doubled, but if you're going to do that you should probably 'cap' the increment at some reasonable size - it might not make sense to double the allocation when you get into the hundreds of megabytes).

Also, I used indexed access to the buffer here as an example, but in a real program I probably wouldn't do that.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void fatal_error(void);

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    int buf_size = 0;
    int buf_used = 0;

    char* buf = NULL;
    char* tmp = NULL;    

    char c;
    int i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (buf_used == buf_size) {
             //need more space in the array

             buf_size += 20;
             tmp = realloc(buf, buf_size); // get a new larger array
             if (!tmp) fatal_error();

             buf = tmp;
        }

        buf[buf_used] = c; // pointer can be indexed like an array
        ++buf_used;
    }

    puts("\n\n*** Dump of stdin ***\n");

    for (i = 0; i < buf_used; ++i) {
        putchar(buf[i]);
    }

    free(buf);

    return 0;
}

void fatal_error(void)
{
    fputs("fatal error - out of memory\n", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

This example combined with examples in other answers should give you an idea of how this kind of thing is handled at a low level.

Answer (score -1):

One way I can imagine is to use a linked list to implement such a scenario, if you need all the numbers entered before the user enters something which indicates the loop termination. (posting as the first option, because have never done this for user input, it just seemed to be interesting. **Wasteful but artistic**)

Another way is to do buffered input. Allocate a buffer, fill it, re-allocate, if the loop continues (**not elegant, but the most rational for the given use-case**).

I don't consider the described to be elegant though. Probably, I would change the use-case (**the most rational**).